# CentOS 6 with User Permission (Read at message)

Tags: centos, centos-6

I have create users on CentOS 6 between test1 and test2
so I login on user test1 on ssh and i tried to access home dir of test2
so why it can access? how i can setting for other users can't access other users?

I already tried to search on google but don't found any answer.

Thank in advance.

Comment: 1) Is this about Centos, RHEL or RedHat? The jumble of tags is confusing and those are all different. Just CentOs-6 and Linux might be better.
2) "so why it can access". Do you want to ask why a user can access the homedir from another user? If so please state so clearly and add the relevant permissions of the directory. (e.g. `ls -ld /home/user1`) and the group memberships of the users.  
(I am guessing that either the homedirs are set to other r-x or that they are set to group r-w and both users share the group 'users').